# Returning error from controller to ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have switch case in my controller and I would like to return error variable which is translated text, into my ajax call. How to return my error message into ajax call?

```
switch (true) {
        case (($to <= $from) && ($statistics > $from)):
            $error = [trans('report.errors.combine')];
            return $error;
            break;
        case ($to <= $from):
            $error = [trans('report.errors.to_date')];
            return $error;
            break;
        case ($statistics > $from):
            $error = [trans('report.errors.statistics')];
            return $error;
            break;
        default:
            $this->generate($request);
    }
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `if`, `else if` & `else` conditions for this instead of `switch case`.

```
   if(($to <= $from) && ($statistics > $from)){
        $error = [trans('report.errors.combine')];
    }
    elseif($to <= $from){
        $error = [trans('report.errors.to_date')];  
    }
    elseif($to <= $from){
        $error = [trans('report.errors.statistics')];
    }
    elseif($statistics > $from){
        $error = [trans('report.errors.statistics')];
    }
    else{
        $content = $this->generate($request);
    }
```

For AJAX response:

```
$res = (isset($error)) ? $error : $content;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res); exit();
```